# How to disable (or increase limit) Zip bomb detection in Tika with Solr config?

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I get some "Zip bomb detected!" exceptions for some of our big HTML files (converted from PDF previously), which are legit files, while trying to index them with Solr. I'd like to either increase the limit for bomb detection or disable it as only a subset of trusted users can input certain well known documents to the system.

Solr documentation states that it's possible to provide a Tika configuration file to it, but I wasn't able to find in the Tika documentation how to set the output threshold of the SecureContentHandler or maybe replace this handler with another one which does not prevent against zip bomb...

How can I specify such change in a Tika config file?

Comment: I think you need to be looking at the SOLR config for this. The Tika config lets you control what parsers and detectors to use. Using / not using / configuring a `SecureContentHandler` is application side, that's before you call Tika

Comment: Exactly, the documentation only mentions about configuring parsers and detectors, but not content handlers. I have no idea on how to set up Tika config in order to configure the SecureContentHandler, which is looking for zip bomb detection. If it's only possible to call it directly from applications, that means I wouldn't be able to handle those documents with Solr... I hope there's some way to achieve what I want with Solr without resorting to implement any custom class in Java...

Comment: You can't do it in the Tika Config, you have to do it in SOLR

Comment: And do you know how to do that in Solr config?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this was caused by a regression in Solr itself at some point. More details in this ticket I created, which was investigated by Tim Allison:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2091

I ended up replacing Tika, by extracting the text from an HTML document directly from my Ruby app using Nokogiri (Nokogiri::HTML(html_content).text). If this affects you and you want it to be fixed in Solr, please create a ticket in the Solr project.